# jQuery UI Tabs: load tabs from individual files/pages without using Ajax or iframe

Tags: jquery, ajax, iframe, user-interface, jquery-ui-tabs

Hi I am using jQuery UI Tabs as a form.

Because of this I can't use Ajax because all tabs/content has to be present when sending the form. The form consists of 9 different tabs, each with lot of code.

Now I want to outsource the content of these tabs to each an individual file (tab1.php, tab2.php, ...).

My solution so far:

1. I could include all the files (tab1.php, ...)in the `<head>` and than load each content as a variable. 
   I don't like this because the code looks messy because of all the escaping.
2. I use iframes. The frames only load when clicked.

   ```
   <div id="tab-1">
       <iframe src="..."></iframe>
   </div>
   ```

Is there a better approach?
Maybe using Ajax load-onceAll or something like that?... maybe something to prevent the iframe from reloading... I don't know.

Comment: I don't understand this requirement: *i can't use ajax because all tabs/content has to be present when sending the form*. Can you elaborate on why you think sending a form precludes you from using ajax?  Also, some code of a mini-example might help to better illustrate what you are doing.

Comment: hi. if someone sends the form ALL the tabs have to be present/loaded since the form depends on all of them. also the form has some interactions (selecting in first tab a checkbox -> alternates some values in second tab and so on....).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can outsource the code to individual files then pull in their content with an Ajax jQuery call when the page loads:

```
var tabs = [
   {
      url: 'tab1.php',
      $ctrl: $('div#tab1')
   },
   {
      url: 'tabN.php',
      $ctrl: $('div#tabN')
   }
];

for(var i = 0; i < tabs.length; ++i)
{
  var data = $.ajax({
    url: tabs[i].url,
    async: false
  }).responseText;
  tabs[i].$ctrl.html(data);
}
```

Then you can use some validation in `onSubmit` functions of the individual tabs forms to ensure they are not posted back until all are finished. This is just one possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried to add the content of the tabs dynamicaly using jQuery? I mean you use a div whit the id `"tab1_div"` and then add the HTML using

```
$("#tab1_div").html("my html content for the tab-page");
```

If that works, you can get the HTML for the tabs by Ajax using `$.get(...)`.